# combine two columns en sort asc

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I've a question about the order by function of MySQL.

In the DB a have rows with two prices. price_min and price_max. For example:

```
ID | NAME   | PRICE_MIN | PRICE_MAX
1  | NAME A | 100       | 350
2  | NAME B | 0         | 250
3  | NAME C | 0         | 90
4  | NAME D | 125       | 500
5  | NAME E | 50        | 0
6  | NAME F | 25        | 0
```

I want to have a query that both columns is sorting from low to high. And if possible showing the rows where the price is MIN and Max double. So in this example i will get 8 results like:

ID: 6, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4.

Is this possible and how will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is more than an `order by`, because you want to change the number of rows.  If I understand correctly, you can use `union all` to get all the non-zero prices and then order by that:

```
select ID, NAME, PRICE_MIN, PRICE_MAX
from ((select ID, NAME, PRICE_MIN, PRICE_MAX, PRICE_MIN as price
       from t
       where price_min <> 0
      ) union all
      (select ID, NAME, PRICE_MIN, PRICE_MAX, PRICE_MAX as price
       from t
       where price_max <> 0
      ) 
     ) p
order by price;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you so much for your quick answer en solution! The last couple of hours i didnt get the right answer or way to search for. This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

With doubles :)

```
SELECT
    id, name, price_min, price_max,
    (price_min != 0 AND price_max != 0) as `double`
FROM (
  SELECT
      *,
      price_min as price
  FROM
      `data`
  WHERE price_min != 0
  UNION
  SELECT
      *,
      price_max as price
  FROM
      `data`
  WHERE price_max != 0
) as `temp`
ORDER BY price
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mXL23CqwALP2sPmBRo8RhA/1)

I chose `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` because you'd get 2 identical rows in case `price_min` and `price_max` are the same for one row.